# How to write array in triple form? e.g. A[i] (Compiler Design)

Tags: compiler-construction

for,  a=b+c,

we write,

op     arg1     arg2 
 
1   +          b           c   
2   =         a              (1)

Then How to write A[i]

Comment: What is wrong with "[] A i" ?

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere. Can you please give me a link?

Comment: Are you using some specific formal model with a fixed set of operations? Since there was no indication of this in the question I just  invented the natural operation.

Comment: I am not using any specific formal model. I am just solving compiler design assignment. Question is translate a=b[i]+c[i] into triples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example expression:

```
a=b+A[i][j]
```

You get the following:

```
op         arg1     arg2

1   index  A        i
2   index (1)       j
3   +      b       (2)
4   =      a       (3)
```

As @Johan suggesgted you can write `[]` instead of `index`.

Comment: what do you mean by index?

Comment: Accessing an element in position `i` of an array `A` is often called "indexing", or just "index" operation. More correct would be to say that `i` is an indexing expression tuple, in your case array is one dimensional and one dimension arrays have an integer index.

Comment: thanks. can you please edit your answer for  2D arrays? e.g A[i][j]